# composer error while composer install and composer update?

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

While running composer install it's giving below error,

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin is locked to version 1.0.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin 1.0.4 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 2
    - magento/composer-root-update-plugin is locked to version 1.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - magento/composer-root-update-plugin 1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 3
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer is locked to version 1.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 4
    - magento/magento-composer-installer is locked to version 0.1.13 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - magento/magento-composer-installer 0.1.13 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 5
    - dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer is locked to version v0.5.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 6
    - magento/magento-composer-installer 0.1.13 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 requires magento/magento-composer-installer >=0.1.11 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-composer-installer[0.1.13].
    - magento/product-community-edition is locked to version 2.4.1 and an update of this package was not requested.

You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2.
```

then if I run composer update below error always,

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
https://repo.magento.com could not be fully loaded (Unable to use a proxy: malformed http_proxy url), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Unable to use a proxy: malformed http_proxy url


update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [-w|--with-dependencies] [-W|--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-s
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got errors installing composer-plugin-api under docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64691483/i-got-errors-installing-composer-plugin-api-under-docker)

Comment: @NicoHaase can you answer if possible

Comment: Answer what? What have you tried to resolve the problem on your own? Where are you stuck?

Comment: after clone composer install if i run its giving below error,

Comment: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Unable to use a proxy: malformed http_proxy url this error @NicoHaase

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all relevant information. Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

This is the main information you're missing:

```
laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin 1.0.4 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint
```

It tells you that you are using Composer v2, while some of your packages still require Composer v1. You should either downgrade Composer to v1, or upgrade the packages.

Upgrading selectively can be done through something like `composer update laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin magento/composer-root-update-plugin`